# how to remove unmatched data while comparing with regex using java

Tags: java, regex

hope doing good.. I am trying to remove unmatched data while comparing with regex using java. And My requirement is like this. 
My Regular Expression is:

```
([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z])(XM|XD|EM|ED)([0-9]{3})(_PRA_)([0-9]{3})
```

It should accept string like this:

```
SHIVA1234AXM123_PRA_123
```

But in case of this if I give any thing `aaSHIVA1234AXM123_PRA_123aa` (or) `SHIVA1234AXccccM123_PRA_123` like this method should give `aaaa` (or) `cccc` like this.
I have tried the following code:

```
public class ExpressionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z])(XM|XD|EM|ED)([0-9]{3})(_PRA_)([0-9]{3})";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

        String str="SHIVA1234AXM123_PRA_123";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);  
        System.out.println(m.groupCount());

        for(int i=1;i<=m.groupCount();i++)
        {
            int start=0;
            int end=0;
            System.out.println("count "+i);
            if(m.lookingAt())
            {
                System.out.println(m.group(i));
                System.out.println("start of group"+m.start(i));
                System.out.println("end of group"+m.end(i));
                start=m.start(i);
                end=m.end(i);
                m.reset();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("ELSE");
                System.out.println(start);
                System.out.println(end);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is for positive case but i need this for false case. And it should be generic for any expression--->string.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the "negative case", you have a contiguous string (no whitespace between characters) that may be "interrupted" by another string, and you want to match that "interrupter" string, correct?

The only way I can think to achieve this is to capture all contiguous non-whitespace characters between each "valid" character. This is gonna be very very ugly:

```
(\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)(?:X|E)(\S*?)(?:M|D)(\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)_(\S*?)P(\S*?)R(\S*?)A(\S*?)_(\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*?)[0-9](\S*)
^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^
```

If I've counted correctly, there are 24 capture groups here. Concatenate all of them!

**EDIT**

By the way, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` to save a few characters:

```
(\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)[A-Z](\S*?)(?:X|E)(\S*?)(?:M|D)(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)_(\S*?)P(\S*?)R(\S*?)A(\S*?)_(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*?)\d(\S*)
^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^       ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^
```

Comment: I think this won't work... how can we write one regular expression like this. as u said this is really ugly. For my case is there any way...

Comment: @ShivaramReddyBollavaram: What do you mean you *think*  it won't work? It does work, and I don't see any way around doing it like this (or in a similar way), unless you can specify more exactly what characters may interrupt your matches at which point(s).

Comment: Event I have tried it... this is only in specific case... And it won't work...@TimPietzcker @acheong87 Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `if (m.matches())` or - in other cases - `while (m.find())`.

For instance to look what might be added in front, add at that spot `(.*)`.

```
//              1   2                      3
String regex = "(.*)([A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z])(XM|XD|EM|ED)([0-9]{3})(_PRA_)([0-9]{3})";


Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Extra in front: '" + m.group(1) + "'");
}
```

Comment: That mean I am not getting can u plz simplify this

Comment: This is not helpful. He has a very specific problem - matches that may be interrupted by spurious characters, and he wants to find those. Your answer does nothing to help him with that.